# Can classic asp and ASP.NET MVC run side-by-side on the same site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, content-management-system, shopping-cart

Just a quick question. I suppose I could just try it but I like StackOverflow because of the quick responses and the comments from people more experienced than I am.

Can classic asp and ASP.NET MVC run side-by-side on the same site? For example; the site might run a CMS written in ASP.NET MVC but need to seamlessly integrate with a cart based in classic asp. Is this possible? Is it a really bad idea?

Of course the preferable situation is to have an both the cart and cms use ASP.NET MVC... but let's say that there is no time to develop the cart and there is already an available classic asp cart.

Comment: by asp classic you mean the very old and ugly asp not ASP NET Web Forms, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. ASP.NET ("classic" WebForms or MVC) can indeed run on the same site as classic ASP.

Comment: make sure to add the routes you want MVC to ignore to your route table

Comment: Also, you may want to look into .net 4.0 extensionless routing so you can turn off runAllManagedModules in the web.config. Otherwise, all .NET modules (session, etc) will be loaded for classic asp pages.  If you are using .net 3.5, check here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx

Comment: @Jab & @Seattle Leonard: Good tips.